# How to explicitly configure TaskBatchExecutionListener in my spring batch application

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud

My spring batch application is not inserting relationship between task and job in `TASK_TASK_BATCH` table.

Spring doc says :

> Associating A Job Execution To The Task In Which It Was Executed
>   Spring Boot provides facilities for the execution of batch jobs easily
>   within an über-jar. Spring Boot’s support of this functionality allows
>   for a developer to execute multiple batch jobs within that execution.
>   Spring Cloud Task provides the ability to associate the execution of a
>   job (a job execution) with a task’s execution so that one can be
>   traced back to the other.

**This functionality is accomplished by using the TaskBatchExecutionListener. By default, this listener is auto configured in any context that has both a Spring Batch Job configured** (via having a bean of type Job defined in the context) and the spring-cloud-task-batch jar is available within the classpath. The listener will be injected into all jobs."

I have all the required jars in my classpath.It's just that I am creating jobs and tasklets dynamically so not using any annotation. As per the doc TaskBatchExecutionListener is responsible for creating mapping in `TASK_TASK_BATCH` table by calling `taskBatchDao's saveRelationship` method.

I am just not able to figure out how to configure `TaskBatchExecutionListener` explicitly in my spring batch application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-task-batch` dependency, and the annotation `@EnableTask` is present, then your application context contains a `TaskBatchExecutionListener` bean that you can inject into your class that dynamically creates the jobs and tasklets.

That might look similar to this:

```
    @Autowired
    JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    TaskBatchExecutionListener taskBatchExecutionListener;

    Job createJob() throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get("myJob")
                .start(createStep())
                .listener(taskBatchExecutionListener)
                .build();
    }
```

I hope that helps. Otherwise please share some minimal code example to demonstrate what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I followed your instruction and managed to register TaskBatchExecutionListener to the job. 
The issue that I am facing currently is taskExecution property is set to null in onTaskStartup callback method. So when beforeJob method is called, it finds taskExecution to be null and doesn't call saveRelationship method.

Although your answer helped me a lot and I would accept your answer, it would be great if you could tell me why taskExecution is null.

Comment: Of course it's hard to tell what goes wrong in your app without seeing it. However, you should be able to debug it yourself (it's open source after all). `TaskExecution` gets instantiated in lines 168-181 of `TaskLifecycleListener`, so that's where I'd start investigating.